# error in R.java file using recyclerview

Tags: android

I have create an app with okhttp,recyclerview, cardview and glitch dependencies added.
no errors were there in java files but when i run the app it shows error in R.java file

```
public static final int recycler-view=0x7f0b005f;
```

hovering over it shows "cannot resolve symbol view"

Here are the imported dependencies in gradle(module) file

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

I have no idea why this is behaving like this since i am relatively new to programming.

PS I have changed the version of cardview and recyclerview from 24 to 26 to match compilesdkversion

Comment: try this Build->Clean Project.

Comment: tried that but no luck

Comment: try this too File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Hi Arun, avoid the use of "-" naming resources, so change the name of "recycler-view"

Comment: this ain't helping either @mihirraj

Comment: If you have a problem inside the resources, Invalidate cache or clean project  couldn´t help, you must solve the problem in your resources first.

Comment: @Jorgesys i believe that was it .. just highlights why basics are so important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally errors in `R.java` file are generated because you have a problem in your resource files.

Remember the convention of how to name resources:

> File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or
>   underscore.

'-' is not a valid file-based resource name character, and you have a resource called `recycler-view`.

Change the name of this resource and build your project again!

Comment: i did the exact mistake of using '-' instead of '_' ... just shows how important conventions are, thnx anyways

Comment: @Arun like you said, the basics are so important :)